# How to add css styles to document.write in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello I'm very new to javascript and doing my first steps I was wondering  if I could style the content of a variable in the document.write instruction and I came to this.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
        .style1{
            background-color: chartreuse;
        }
    </style>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var name1;
        name1=prompt("Write your name");
        document.write('<p class="style1">'+name1+'</p>');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I got that solved by reviewing some posts here the question is how does this actually work?

```
document.write('<p class="style1">'+name1+'</p>');
```

I'm not sure I understand why I need to put ' for this instruction could somebody explain that please thank you btw I'm sorry this is a very basic question but I would like to know also if you guys have some more ways to style a document.write it would be nice to know .

Comment: Please have a good understanding how CSS/Style works. Please go through https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS.

Comment: The single quote char is there so that the double quotes don't need to be escaped. Technically you dont need the single quote chars as you infer. You could use double quotes on the outside, but all your inside double quotes will need to be escaped as in `\"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest taking a slightly different approach. You can add a div to your HTML with an ID of "test" (or whatever you'd like), then edit the innerHTML of that div like so:

```js
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = name1;
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.write();` is writing a text in your HTML File.
so if you write like this:

```
<script>document.write("<p>blah</p>");</script>
```

then you are writing html Source like `<p>blah</p>`.

Answer (score 0):

document.write : Write HTML elements with text directly to the HTML document

```
 var name1;
 name1=prompt("Write your name");
 document.write('<p class="style1">'+name1+'</p>');
```

1. Create a variable named `name1`
2. Give a value to `name1` variable from user input in prompt alert
3. Write `p` element with class `style1` and its content is value from `name1` to HTML document